# O que significa Java FE e BE?

Tags: java, terminologia

Estou começando com a linguagem Java e hoje me deparei com um texto mencionando Java (**FE e BE**). O que significam essas siglas?

Answer (score 9):

Desenvolvedor Java Front-End (FE) e Java Back-End (BE).
Não é a melhor definição, mas [aqui está](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front-end_e_back-end) uma definição pra se ter uma ideia.

Os termos FE e BE não é restrito a Java, pode se referir a qualquer linguagem de programação.

Comment: Pode ser também Front-End e Back-End de alguma aplicação, não necessariamente Java.

Answer (score 0):

FE se refere ao front end. Geralmente JavaScript e afins (AngujarJs, React, JQuery, etc.), "o que roda no browser".
BE se refere ao back end ou server side da aplicação, "o que roda no servidor".

No caso, Java FE deve referir-se à Servlet e JSP, enquanto Java BE ao restante da aplicação.